# Move multiple userstories to existing feature in TFS?

Tags: tfs, user-stories

In TFS we have a feature called Inbox. All users of TFS can register userstories (idea’s, suggestions etc.) under this feature. Productowners validate once in the month all the userstories and link them to another feature. This is a manual action that takes a lot of time.

Is there a possibility to create a query, export the query to Excel, change the featureID and publish it again?
I already did some attempts but in most of the attempts the connection with the original feature was lost.

We are using TFS 2013.

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Backlog in TFS web access to drag User story from one Feature to another. It's very convenient.

[image]

**Adding:**

You are right that in TFS 2013, we can't drag items on Backlogs. But we can drag them in a query result in VS. I just tested with VS2015+TFS2013.5. Select "**Work Items and Direct Links**" in a work item query, and add clauses as the screenshot:

[image]

Then you can drag the User Story to any Feature in the Query result. After save the result, the User Story will go to the new Feature:

[image]

Comment: We use TFS2013 and it's not possible to drag and drop unfortunately.

Comment: Please check the adding information I just did, which should help you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. There is Add-in to Excel -  Team Foundation Add-in. You can use it to load query results into excel(New List in Add-in tab), change come fields in the results (you can customize fields in query's Column options) and then publish the results.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but that is what I have done. I created a query with multiple levels. In Excel I changed the Id of the userstory's and publish again. Result: userstory's without feature id.

Comment: oh. I read your question incorrecrly. So, you need to link multiple User stories from one feature to another?

Comment: No problem. Yes that's what I meant.

Comment: I have not found column "links and attachments" in tfs 2015 queries. Actually i'd try to use TfsAggregator [here is a link](https://github.com/tfsaggregator/tfsaggregator). Create a rule which will link workitems as you want. Make a field like ParentId. Once a month set this field in needed workitems using tfs query and aggregator will link wirkitems  to the workitem with ID from this field.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to check if tfsaggregator fit my needs. If so I will mark this as accepted.